# google app engine error ,and i can't open it now.(python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

the error is :

---

### Errors occurred

See the logfile 'D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe.log' for details

Why?

Comment: I'd recommend seeing the logfile at 'D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe.log' for details, and then posting those details here so we can help you better :)

Comment: You'd think so.  I just got this error, and there is actually no log file there.

Answer (score 11):

Find your home directory (open command prompt, run "set home" to see what it is).  Go to that directory and delete the directory called "Google"

more here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2299

Comment: This solved my problem, but I really don't know how it happened that a folder named Google got in there.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:
Note: The wrong directories are stated above.

1. Go to C:\Users\your username\Google directory.
2. Delete google_appengine_launcher.ini and google_appengine_projects.ini
3. Appengine should now start successfully, absent error message.

Answer (score 2):

yeah just like RyanW mentioned the link, **Delete** the .ini files viz. **google_appengine_launcher.ini & google_appengine_projects.ini** in the user Directory in folder named Google.

Answer (score 2):

Had this error as well.
No log file.
C:/Users//Google/ was empty and no ini file there.
[Ivan's solution](https://code.google.com/p/google-appengine-wx-launcher/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=6) didn't help.

I'm running a 64bit Win8 machine and this is what I had to do:
Remove my 64 bit python 2.7 install
Install 32 bit python 2.7 ([direct link](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/python-2.7.9.msi))
launch googleappengine installer and choose "Repair".

Voila.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough points to provide a comment on the answers above hence the stand alone answer. If you delete the ini files as per the other answers the pathways to your projects in the launcher will likely also be gone. In my case however I simply moved the ini files out of the C:\Users\your username\Google directory and then after opening and closing the launcher successfully once I reinstated the ini files into the Google directory again, after which the launcher worked and the project pathways were retained.