# Unable to open Google App engine launcher

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Getting the same error as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643081/google-app-engine-error-and-i-cant-open-it-now-python) .

**I am getting the same Error** :
See the logfile 'D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe.log' for details

**But solution there is not helping me**.I have no such log file created. Deleting the folder C:\user\Google is not helping!!

This [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/gTmK8-dS90Y) discusses the same problem as mine but I am clueless what has been done.

Please Help (stuck with this problem for 2 days now ).

Edit :
Running with appengine_launcher.bat gives same error.

Comment: *This ques is duplicate of the one above.* Then don't post a new question, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google app engine error ,and i can't open it now.(python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643081/google-app-engine-error-and-i-cant-open-it-now-python)

Comment: @MartijnPieters but no answer posted there addresses my problem.

Comment: I'm sorry that you feel the question has not been answered to your satisfaction. You'll need to put more information in your own question then on what you tried and how that didn't work for you. Make sure your question can stand on its own instead.

Comment: But if the question is just covering the same ground, asking it anew won't bring more answers.